# Unexpected End of Input Error on javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am really stumped on an end of input error I am getting. I have isolated it to the following code. When I remove the code the error goes away.

Does anyone see what the error could be regarding? The console doesn't point at anything specific, other than highlighting the closing script tag.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    //Arrow Down
    $('#arrowDownWrap').click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('#home-section2').offset().top -140}, 1000);
    });

    //Phone Img slide
    let last_known_scroll_position = 0;
    let ticking = false;

    function doSomething(scroll_pos) {
        // Do something with the scroll position
        document.querySelector('#homeBoxGridRight img').style.transform = 'translateX(-' + (scroll_pos * 0.1) + '%)';
        document.querySelector('#homeBoxGridRight img').style.transform += 'translateY(-50%)';
    }

    window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
        last_known_scroll_position = window.scrollY;

        if (!ticking) {
            window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
                doSomething(last_known_scroll_position);
                ticking = false;
            });

            ticking = true;
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: can you include some of your other code?

Comment: try using mozilla developer edition. It has pretty good debugging console about this kind of issues. Since in your website the problem where this is happening is written in a single line , it is hard to see where it happened. Test it yourself with your test server

Answer (score 0):

This code has an error:

```
$('#arrowDownWrap').click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#home-section2').offset().top -140}, 1000);
});
```

And this is the solution:

```
$('#arrowDownWrap').click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#home-section2').offset().top -140}, 1000);
    }); // <-- this line is missing
});
```

Comment: Thanks but the closing brackets were in the code. The closing brackets are here `-140}, 1000)`.

Answer (score 0):

You have two closing functions at the end of script tag. Remove one and add it after the 'arrowDownWrap' function,

Your code will look like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
//Arrow Down
  $('#arrowDownWrap').click(function() {
      $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: $('#home-section2').offset().top -140}, 1000);
      });
   });

//Phone Img slide
let last_known_scroll_position = 0;
let ticking = false;

function doSomething(scroll_pos) {
    // Do something with the scroll position
     document.querySelector('#homeBoxGridRight img').style.transform =   'translateX(-' + (scroll_pos * 0.1) + '%)';
    document.querySelector('#homeBoxGridRight img').style.transform += 'translateY(-50%)';
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    last_known_scroll_position = window.scrollY;

    if (!ticking) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
            doSomething(last_known_scroll_position);
            ticking = false;
        });

        ticking = true;
      }
  });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi  You are missing the closing tags after the $arrowDownWrap , Instead you are using it just above the script tag twice.This can happen dont get degraded by that . Good luck the fix is bellow .

```
           window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    last_known_scroll_position = window.scrollY;

    if (!ticking) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
            doSomething(last_known_scroll_position);
            ticking = false;
        });

        ticking = true;
    }
});
});//first remove this part here . It is repeated above which is giving you the error. IDE finds two endtags at the same point .
```

Secondly add the removed closing tags here  and close the function  , which you have missed. Voila . Good luck

```
         $('#arrowDownWrap').click(function() {
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#home-section2').offset().top -140}, 1000);
}); // <-- this  is where you missed it
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**you didn't closed the function properly you have  missed the curle braces and paranthesis and semicolon at the end of the function.**